# Retrieve Public Outlook Calendar Appointments?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar

I am trying to retrieve the appointments for the same day from any given user's name.
So far, I am able to retrieve my own appointments for today with the code below.

```
else if (UserSelection == "2")
            {
                //Create the Outlook application
                Outlook.Application oApplication = new Outlook.Application();

                // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
                Outlook.NameSpace oNameSpace = oApplication.GetNamespace("mapi");

                //Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
                oNameSpace.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

                // Get the Calendar folder.
                Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

                // Get the appointments (items) collection from the Calendar folder.
                Outlook.Items oItems = oCalendar.Items;
                oItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;


                List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> lst = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();

                foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in oItems)
                {
                    if (item.Start.Day == DateTime.Today.Day && item.Start.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && item.Start.Year == DateTime.Today.Year)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Organizer: " + item.Organizer);
                        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + item.Start.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("End: " + item.End.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Location: " + item.Location);
                        Console.WriteLine("Recurring: " + item.IsRecurring);
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + item.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine("Attendees: " + item.OptionalAttendees);
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
                }


                //Get the last appointment(item)
                //Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)oItems.GetLast();

                //Show the appointment(item) in outlook.
                //oAppt.Display(true);

                // Done. Log off.
                oNameSpace.Logoff();

                //Clean up.
                oItems = null;
                oCalendar = null;
                oNameSpace = null;
                oApplication = null;

                Console.ReadLine();
```

This works fine. However, the following code below doesnt return the given user "userName"'s appointments.

```
if (UserSelection == "1")
        //try (used for error handling) 
        {
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();


            Outlook.Application oApplication;
            oApplication = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNameSpace = oApplication.GetNamespace("mapi");
            oNameSpace.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNameSpace.CreateRecipient(userName);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

            // Get the appointments (items) collection from the Calendar folder.
            Outlook.Items oItems = oCalendar.Items;
            oItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;



            List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> lst = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();

            foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in oItems)
            {
                if (item.Start.Day == DateTime.Today.Day && item.Start.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && item.Start.Year == DateTime.Today.Year)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Organizer: " + item.Organizer);
                    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + item.Start.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("End: " + item.End.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Location: " + item.Location);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recurring: " + item.IsRecurring);
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + item.Subject);
                    Console.WriteLine("Attendees: " + item.OptionalAttendees);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }



                //Show the appointment(item) in outlook.
                //oAppt.Display(true);

                // Done. Log off.
                oNameSpace.Logoff();

                // Clean up.

                oItems = null;
                oCalendar = null;
                oNameSpace = null;
                oApplication = null;

                Console.ReadLine();
```

The code line producing the error is `foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in oItems)`
The error returned is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8834010F"

Any help to make this work would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the exception fire immediately or only after you process a few appointments?

Comment: Only after typing a username and pressing enter

Comment: If i type my own name, appointments are returned, but if i type someone else, the error is returned. Possibly a permissions issue? I have access to public calendars so should be able to pull the appointments ok?

Comment: What I am getting at is that it is possible that you are possibly running out of RPC channels (since GetSharedDefaultFolder will most likely return an online store, not cached). So how many items does your loop process before the error is raised?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from releasing underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. See [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also I'd suggest using the **Find**/**FindNext** or **Restrict** methods of the Items class. You can read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)